# Remover elementos repetidos de um vetor multidimensional

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um código para conseguir remover linhas duplicadas de um vetor com cadastros de clientes.

Esse vetor é "`tabela[1000][3]`"

Então eu tenho por exemplo:

```
1ºlinha - "joao" " rua: asasdfasdfs" "cep: 21412354125"

2ºlinha - "matheus" " rua: asdfasdfasdf" "cep: 21412354125"

3ºlinha repetida - "jonas" " rua: asdfasdf" "cep: 21412354125"

4ºlinha - "guilherme" " rua: asdfasdfasdf" "cep: 21412354125"

5ºlinha - "gabriel" " rua: asasdfasdfasdfasdfs" "cep: 21412354125"

6ºlinha repetida - "jonas" " rua: asdfasdf" "cep: 21412354125"]
```

existem nomes da primeira coluna que são repetidas, e eu gostaria de remover essa linha por completo, então pensei em fazer um novo vetor apenas com linhas não repetidas comparando linha por linha do vetor que seria o filtrado com o antigo:

```
int filt_next = 0;

    for(int atual = 0; atual < tabela.length; atual++){
        for(int passando = 0; passando < filtrado.length; passando++){

            String comp1 = tabela[atual][0];
            String comp2 = filtrado[passando][0];

            if(comp1 == comp2){

                break;

            }

            if(comp1 != comp2){

                filtrado[filt_next][0] = tabela[atual][0];
                filtrado[filt_next][1] = tabela[atual][1];
                filtrado[filt_next][2] = tabela[atual][2];


                filt_next++;

                break;
            }


        }

    }
```

A ideia é que se a posição do primeiro vetor for igual a do segundo vetor ele iria apenas dar um break e sair do laço, ignorando a repetição.
E caso passe por todas as posições e seja diferente ele adicionaria tal posição no novo vetor.

Porem a parte que deveria pegar as posições iguais é ignorado, e as Strings iguais são consideradas diferentes, sendo adicionadas ao vetor dos filtrados.

```
 if(comp1 == comp2){
    break;

}
```

Não consigo entender o que fiz de errado.

Comment: Comparação de `Strings` em java é com `equals` e não com `==`. Ainda assim não está claro qual a informação exata que o arquivo tem. E melhor solução seria à medida que lê linhas do arquivo não adiciona a uma lista de clientes se o cliente já existir, e depois apenas tem que voltar a escrever os clientes que leu

Comment: a tabela tem 3 colunas, e a primeira coluna tem o nome dos clientes, eu só preciso comparar essa primeira coluna, sem perder a ordem dos dados das outras 2 colunas...

No caso que você disse, comparar logo quando lê as linhas do arquivo, e não colocar as linhas em um vetor para compara-lo depois?

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que compara strings deve utilizar o método equals ao invés de == ou !=. Substitua o seu código para ter:

```
if (comp1.equals(comp2)) {
    break;
}

if(!comp1.equals(comp2)){
    ...
    break;
}
```